# How to stop a webpage from executing javascript that resides inside a textarea or as value to input (type text)?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, textarea

I have an anoying problem with a page. If I have a textarea or textbox with its value (set on serverside) to eg. "alert('hello');" that script is executed upon load of the page.

Well why dont you encode the string before you set it as value to the textbox you ask? Then special characters like åäö will also be encoded and thats a solution that works for me.

Anyone have any clue how to solve this?

Comment: If your page is evaluating textbox values as scripts, you've got a serious issue. You should post some of your code here to better diagnose the problem.

Comment: This is what the source look like and it pops up a hello messagebox upon page loading:

<input name="tb" value="&lt;script&gt;alert('hello');&lt;/script&gt;" maxlength="50" id="id" class="textbox" style="width: 100%;" type="text">

Comment: I would know how to solve this too. I am doing some UI testing using Selenium WebDriver, and when trying to SendKeys to a text field that has a javascript it just hangs....

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for all convenience, I solved it, the problem was that I focused on the textbox but the problem was that the same text was applied to a hidden div so that script was the executing one. Well well thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but I gather that you output the textarea contents as html upon form submit? If you are using php, just run the textarea contents through http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars to fix the issue while preserving the characters you don't want to lose.

Other scripting languages should have simillar funcitons, or in the worst case, writing your own should not pose a problem.